# How do i get the status of my response when using fetch in react-native?

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

I am making Log In page for my react native application. My api sends different response when my username and password are valid and invalid. So I want to track and save the status of my response in some state variable and then later perform function accordingly. Please suggest me way to do that.

```
  doSignUp() {
   console.log("inside post api");
   fetch('MyApiUrl', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',

                },


      body: JSON.stringify({
      password: this.state.password,
      email:this.state.email,
      name: this.state.firstname,
      last_name :this.state.last_name,
      mobile:this.state.mobile,
      ssn:"2222222"

     })
      }).then((response) => {console.log('response:',response.status);
             response.json()}
        .then((responseData) => {
                                console.log("inside responsejson");
                                console.log('response object:',responseData)
                                console.log('refresh token:',responseData[0].token.refresh_token)
                                console.log('access token:',responseData[0].token.access_token);



         }).done();
```

}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to know the http status code of your fetch request.

Usually your response object includes a "status" property. So you should be able to receive the status code by using this:

```
response.status
```

In case of a successful request this will return 200.

Comment: it seems I edited the answer when you were testing this, the status property is available in the response property of your first .then() callback

Comment: Yes I edited the above code. The problem that  now I am getting is the responseData is not in json format , this must be happening due to asynchronous call back code I think, Please suggest me some way to do that. The output that I am recieving on console is ---->  inside post api
SignUp.js:35 response: 201
SignUp.js:39 inside responsejson
SignUp.js:40 response object: undefined
ExceptionsManager.js:61 Cannot read property '0' of undefined    @manpenaloza

Comment: my goal is to get the status code if it would be success then only I will save access token else I would show msg of invalid username/password. @manpenaloza